# C++ deleting minimum element in binary tree

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

Can anyone explain to me why the `delete_min()` function does not work?  I have been trying to figure this out for hours now.

I have tried different variations of the function, but it seems to either delete the wrong thing, only alter data and not delete it, or delete the wrong thing.  Also, the insertion function doesn't always work properly after `delete_min()` is called, so I'm sure this has something to do with pointers.

Here is the function:

```
int BinaryTree::delete_min_helper(TreeNode *node){

   while(node->left != NULL){
      node = node->left;
   }

  if(node == root){
     puts("attempted to delete root");
     return 1;
  }

  delete node;
  node = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

And here is a compilable example:

```
#ifndef _TREE_H_
#define _TREE_H_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct TreeNode {
  int val;
  char *str;
  TreeNode *left;
  TreeNode *right;
};

class BinaryTree {
  public:

  BinaryTree();
  ~BinaryTree();

  int insert_node(unsigned int val, char *str);
  TreeNode *find_min();
  int delete_min();
  void print();

 private:

 int insert_node_helper(TreeNode *&node, unsigned int val, char *str);
 int delete_min_helper(TreeNode *node);
 void print_helper(TreeNode *node);

 TreeNode *root;  
};

#endif

BinaryTree::BinaryTree(){
  this->root = NULL;
}

BinaryTree::~BinaryTree(){
}

int BinaryTree::insert_node(unsigned int val, char *str){
  return insert_node_helper(this->root, val, str);
}

int BinaryTree::insert_node_helper(TreeNode *&node, unsigned int val, char *str){

  if(node == NULL){
    node = new TreeNode;
    node->val = val;
    node->str = strdup(str);
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    if(node != NULL){
      return 0;
    }else{
      puts("inserted null node");
      return 1;
   }
 }else if(val <= node->val){
   return insert_node_helper(node->left, val, str);
 }else if(val > node->val){
   return insert_node_helper(node->right, val, str);
 }

 return 1;
}

void BinaryTree::print(){
  print_helper(this->root);
}


void BinaryTree::print_helper(TreeNode *node){

    if(node != NULL){
      print_helper(node->right);
      printf("%d occurrences of \"%s\"\n", node->val, node->str);
      print_helper(node->left);
    }

}

TreeNode *BinaryTree::find_min(){
  TreeNode *temp = this->root;
  while(temp->left != NULL){
    temp = temp->left;
  }
  return temp;
}

int BinaryTree::delete_min(){
   return delete_min_helper(root);
}

int BinaryTree::delete_min_helper(TreeNode *node){

   while(node->left != NULL){
     node = node->left;
   }

  if(node == root){
    puts("attempted to delete root");
    return 1;
  }

  delete node;
  node = NULL;
  return 0;
}

#include <time.h>

int main(){

  BinaryTree bt;

  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     bt.insert_node(rand() % 20, "test");
  }

  bt.print();
  printf("min val = %d\n", bt.find_min()->val);
  puts("#################################");
  bt.delete_min();
  bt.print();
  printf("min val = %d\n", bt.find_min()->val);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your delete function simply destroys the `TreeNode` object.  It doesn't rewire the pointers to any of the attached nodes.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia,  but it is always deleting the minimum element, which will always be a leaf node with no children.  I shouldn't have to worry about rewiring, right?

Comment: the parent Node of the leaf Node will have an invalid `left` pointer, and the deleted leaf node may have a `right` branch.

Comment: @user2052561 Note that your previous solution in the earlier question, taking a reference-to-pointer, did at least attempt to rewire the parent-of-min pointer. That's kind of what I meant when I said you should try to understand what the code does rather than copying what you see all over the place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things come to mind right away:

1. a parent node is still pointing at the node which you deleted
2. the node you're deleting might have a `node->right` pointer hanging off of it, which you are lopping off the tree, instead of re-hooking it back into the tree.

There might be more problems, but you need to address these issues at a bare minimum.

Answer (score -1):

Reference from his parent still point to some address in memory.

Try this:

```
int BinaryTree::delete_min_helper(TreeNode *node){

   TreeNode *prev = NULL;
   while(node->left != NULL){
      prev = node;
      node = node->left;
   }

  if(node == root){
     puts("attempted to delete root");
     return 1;
  }

  prev->left = NULL;

  delete node;
  node = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are still orphaning `node->right`. However, I do not think you should give complete answers to an obvious homework question.